# Time complexity of static_cast for enum class

Tags: c++, enums

Suppose I have the following in C++

```
enum class my_enum {
    item1, item2, ..., itemn, last_
};
```

I would like to be able to convert between `my_enum` and `int`s easily
(for mapping/positioning purposes), using e.g. `static_cast<size_t>(enum_object)`. Now, what is the time complexity, in terms of `n`, of
this operation? Is it `O(n)` or `O(1)`?
Even more bizarre suggestion, does one guarantee an `O(log(n))` time by
storing something like `map<my_enum,size_t>`?

Comment: as you can see in https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/QVymHx
even in -O0 static_cast is just a mov instruction in assembly which is O(1)

Comment: A `enum` only has one value at any time at runtime. When you cast it, you only need to cast that one value. It sounds like you may be concerned that it has to cast every possible value. Casting to or from an `enum` is identical as casting to or from it's underlying type in terms of runtime cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of converting an `enum` value to an integer is `O(1)`.

Enums are nothing more than a number at runtime, so most probably no code needs to be executed for the conversion at all. Some code *may* be executed if the *underlying type* of the enum (`int` by default) and the conversion target type have different byte representations.

In other words, these two conversions lead to the same assembly code:

```
MyEnum enumVal = ...;
T integer = static_cast<T>(enumVal);

std::underlying_type_t<MyEnum> underlying = ...;
T integer = static_cast<T>(underlying);
```

Regarding `std::map`, the complexity depends on the operation; see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for details. Insertion is `O(log(n))`, where `n` here is the map size (number of elements).

The number of enumerators never has an influence on time complexity -- in C++, there is not even an easy way to compute the number of enumerators without extra "count" enumerators or macros.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** O(1) for the cast, 0(log(n)) for insertion in a map and 0(1) for insertion into unordered_map

**Long answer:**

enum are mapped to int so the enum is actually an int ***inside*** memory

Assume that you have:

```
enum MyEnum{enum1, enum2};
```

static_cast is done at **compile time** so the following operation is exactly like an assignement in terms of complexity

```
    int a=static_cast<int>(MyEnum::enum1);
```

Regarding the insertion, mapping, please refer to the STL, you have all complexities detailled

Comment: this code compiles, could you detail what is wrong/missing?

Comment: To be clear about it, `enum MyEnum` introduces its enumerator names, like `enum1`, into two scopes, both inside `MyEnum` and outside. `enum class MyEnum` introduces its enumerator names only inside `MyEnum`. If you are always going to use `MyEnum::enum1` and don't need plain `enum1`, you might as well use `enum class`, as a more modern alternative.

Comment: My fault, obviously missed some update in the standard... Interestingly, standard doesn't speak of that double scope, solely gives an example for  (https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#11). That double scope did *not* exist before C++11, though.